# Modifying HTML5 snake game with image file for head

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've followed a tutorial on how to create a HTML5 Snake game but I want to modify it. The tutorial can be found at http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2009/12/30/html5-canvas-snake-game

I want to have an image file for the head of the snake which is 10x10 pixels while the rest of the snake is the regular color. Could anyone help me accomplish this with the code from the tutorial?

Imagine that this is the snake and [x] represents the head. I would like to modify the head to contain an image.

[x][ ][ ][ ]

I know that to draw an image in the canvas you would use the drawImage method, but don't know how to use it for this specific game.

Thx in advance :)

Comment: What kind of answer are you expecting? Compete code sample? If you really know `drawImage()` you should be able to paste the image at the position of snake head right? =)

Comment: I wouldn't be asking the question if I wasn't sure how to approach it myself. I would just like to know how I would implement an image for the head with the code provided from the tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After this line... `this.gridSize = 10;` add

```
this.snakeHead = new Image();
this.snakeHead.src = "/path/to/my/image.png";
```

Then rewrite the following function like this...

```
function drawSnake() {
  snakeBody.push([currentPosition['x'], currentPosition['y']]);
  ctx.drawImage(snakeHead,currentPosition['x'], currentPosition['y'],gridSize,gridSize);
  if(snakeBody.length > 1) {
    last = snakeBody[1];
    ctx.fillRect(last['x'], last['y'], gridSize, gridSize); // this might be last[0] and last[1] here
  }
  if (snakeBody.length > 3) {
    var itemToRemove = snakeBody.shift();
    ctx.clearRect(itemToRemove[0], itemToRemove[1], gridSize, gridSize);
  }
}
```

I haven't run this, this is a guide only to get you started.

Comment: I modified the code slightly based on what you provided, but am having some problems still.

function drawSnake() {

  snakeBody.push([currentPosition['x'], currentPosition['y']]);
  ctx.drawImage(snakeHead,currentPosition['x'], currentPosition['y'],gridSize,gridSize);

  if(snakeBody.length > 3) {
    last = snakeBody[snakeLength-1];
    ctx.fillRect(last[0], last[1], gridSize, gridSize); // this might be last[0] and last[1] here
 }

if (snakeBody.length > snakeLength) {
    var itemToRemove = snakeBody.shift();
    ctx.clearRect(itemToRemove[0], itemToRemove[1], gridSize, gridSize);
  }

}

Comment: what exactly is the problem? (I don't have a link...) Surely this would draw the snake head images throughout the length of the snake...

Comment: When the snake length increases in size, you can see exactly 3 tiles of the snake head which eventually disappear. Any suggestions?